# Capture the previous value when onkeydown is executed

Tags: javascript

Need help in event handling. In my scenario, I have a textbox with default value 35 and cursor is set to before the 3. There is a event for this text box which is onkeydown. When I press 4, IE and Safari captures the previous value of the text which is 35. But Mozilla and Chrome captures the new value which is 435.

I need the javascript code which can capture the previous value of the textbox when onkeydown is fired.

Need your hands :(

Comment: Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJwKX/). It works fine using Chrome Version 19.0.1084.52 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Tested in IE, Chrome, FF, Opera and it works

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="35" />
</div>
<script>
       $("input").keydown(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
</script>
```